# Firefox tracks downloads, but are uploads logged somewhere?

Tags: firefox, browser, http

Is there a way to find the history of uploaded files like there is for downloaded files? If there is not a GUI for this, is there a log file I can comb through for this information?

I am looking for a retroactive solution.

Thank you

Comment: The question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of how the internet and browsers work and the role the play re downloading and uploading, but that does not make it a bad question, just a question the answer to which will be at an angle OP did not suspect.

Comment: Sterling, the answer below is basically OK, but I think it may be more clear to say simply that while the browser downloads most files websites, websites do the uploading, not the browser. Yes, the browser displays the page that contains the upload elements, but the upload itself is not handled by the browser and so is not recorded by the browser.

Comment: @music2myear, yes, but my question was more of a holistic sanity check. Is it the case or possible that the browser allows access to a local file and logs that information somewhere?

Comment: @music2myear: Your “websites do the uploading, not the browser” comment baffles me.  Websites can’t swoop down, snoop in your computer, and grab files.  Any file data that goes from the PC’s local storage to the web site is read from the file and written to the network socket *by the browser.*

Comment: It is a simplistic explanation, but it basically describes why the browser does not have a single list of uploaded files. When a browser downloads a file it uses a protocol determined by the site to request and then store binary content. It does so using its own engine. When a site requests data it uses any of a plethora of frameworks, plugins, or other methods to interact with the OS managed file system, through the browser, within the user's permissions, and then transfers the selected content. The browser may be a broker, but it does not perform the upload itself.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way (except logging all of your traffic with a proxy, which is not retroactive) to have an "upload history", as technically there are multiple ways uploads happen behind the scenes. At most you can see the most recent folder from where the file has been uploaded, just go to that page and click upload.

Comment: It may happen to be true that Firefox doesn’t log uploads, but why do you say «There is no way … to have an ‘‘upload history’’ ….»?  What do you mean by «technically there are multiple ways uploads happen behind the scenes», and how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: It is relevant because that is the key reason why the browser doesn't have this list.